# What is a Hikami box?

Tags: particle-physics, condensed-matter, definition, feynman-diagrams

Can anyone tell me what is the physical meaning of the image below ([Hikami boxes](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=Hikami+box))? (Especially the dashed line.)

Furthermore (and this is less important), why are these boxes needed for weak anti-localization calculation?

I have no formal training in QFT so I would love to understand it.

https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.92.241402
https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.06892

[image: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.92.241402]